# Under any Scheme standard, is (let (x y z) x) valid code?

Tags: scheme, common-lisp, elisp, let, language-comparisons

In both Emacs Lisp and Common Lisp, the following returns `nil`

```lisp
(let (x y z)
  x)
```

yet in every Scheme that I've tried, it throws an error.

Has the above been acceptable under any Scheme standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the posted code was *never* legal in standard Scheme. For all Scheme standards since [R1RS (1978)](https://standards.scheme.org/official/r1rs.pdf) `let` has had the syntax: `(let ((var1 form1) ...) expr1 expr2 ...)`. The original Scheme paper by [Sussman and Steele (1975)](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/5794/AIM-349.pdf?sequence=2&isAllowed=y) did not even use `let`.

Note that, e.g., `(let () 42)` *is* legal in both Scheme and in Common Lisp, i.e., it is legal to have a `let` form with *no* bindings.

Comment: In the first lambda paper Scheme borrows heavily from MacLisp, but `let` is a [lisp machine feature](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/25231/when-was-let-introduced-to-lisp) and wasn't introduced to MacLisp until 1979 so  in fact Scheme second revision had it before MacLisp :-o

Comment: @Sylwester -- that's a really interesting Q&A. _"...so in fact Scheme second revision had it before MacLisp"_: the _first_ revised report had it before MacLisp ;)

Comment: You're right. Second version / first revision was mixed there 

Answer (score 0):

"Any version of Scheme ever" is a very broad brush, and it could take some research to rule out all of history. But in the modern Schemes I know, it is not allowed, and the R5RS standard clearly does not allow it, by specifying that [the bindings for a `let` must come in name/value pairs](https://conservatory.scheme.org/schemers/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/), and not specifying what a name without a value would mean.